# how to click open a pen in Full Page View by default please?

Tags: codepen

How to click open a pen in `Full Page View` by default please? For example, I would like to open below pen in full page view.

```
codepen.io/Hance/pen/aLjrJJ
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Hance/full/aLjrJJ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple google search would have sufficed in this case, but anyway

> **You can access the Full Page view of any Pen from the "Change View" menu in the header.** - [Codepen Blog](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/views/full-page-view/)

To directly view the pen in full page, use `/full/` in your link

```
codepen.io/Hance/full/aLjrJJ
```